# Retrieve value from the Object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following object which contains an array of `NSDictionary`. I wonder how could I able to get the sum of `Quantity` from this object.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C there is a very convenient way using *KVC Collection Operators*:

```
NSNumber *sum = [sharedData.orderItems valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.Quantity.integerValue"];
NSInteger integerSum = sum.integerValue;
```

The other simple operators are:

- `@count` - count of objects
- `@avg` - average value
- `@max` - maximum value
- `@min` - minimum value

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum=0;

for(NSDictionary *item in sharedData.orderitems){
    sum = sum + [[item objectForKey:@"Quantity"] intValue];
}

NSLog(@"Sum = %d",sum);
```

Comment: you mean `sharedData.orderItems`