# sum and store data from for statement

Tags: objective-c

I need to memorize the data that comes out of this FOR statement

```
for (UTEModelSportWalkRun *model in arraySport) {
    NSLog(@"sport *** time = %@, Total step = %ld, walkDistance = %f , walkCalorie = %f, runDistance = %f, runCalorie = %f",
    model.time, (long)model.stepsTotal, model.walkDistances, model.walkCalories, model.runDistances, model.runCalories);
}
```

I need to add up all the model.stepTotal and memorize the sum in some way. Now it comes out like this:

> sport *** time = 2019-05-30-17, Total step = 14, walkDistance = 9.764355, walkCalorie = 0.346086, runDistance = 0.000000, runCalories = 0.000000
>   sport *** time = 2019-05-31-10, Total step = 67, walkDistance = 46.729411, walkCalorie = 1.656267, runDistance = 0.000000, runCalories = 0.000000
>   sport *** time = 2019-05-31-11, Total step = 520, walkDistance = 362.676028, walkCalorie = 12.854608,
>   runDistance = 0.000000, runCalories = 0.000000

.....

Comment: Explain what keeps you from adding the stepTotals inside the loop.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476804/retrieve-value-from-the-object/44476978#44476978

Answer (score 0):

```
long count = 0;
for (UTEModelSportWalkRun *model in arraySport) {
      count += (long)model.stepsTotal;
}
```

Declare the variable before the loop and enjoy accessing it after. It's called Scoping.